# Converting SQL statement from LIMIT to TOP C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqlite, sql-server-2012

I am working on an application that was implemented using a SQLite database. I am currently in the process of adding the ability to use MSSQL as well. The complicated part is that it will need to be able to use either engine depending on the needs. There are a handful of different syntax differences that have to be accounted for. The biggest problem child I have come across is LIMIT vs TOP. I have written some logic to convert the SQLite statements into the proper format for MSSQL. My function for converting the LIMIT to TOP seems to be working, but it ended up being pretty ugly. I wanted to post it here and see if anyone had ideas for a cleaner method of completing this. I also wanted to see if anyone noticed any glaring issues that I have missed. The biggest problem I ran into is the possibility of nested select statements with possible LIMIT statements on them as well. I ended up pulling the statement apart into its individual parts, changing them from LIMIT to TOP, and then rebuilding the statement. There might even be an overall better way to do this that I am missing. Thanks ahead of time if you spend the time to take a look.

```
private static string ConvertLimitToTop(string commandText)
{
    string processCommand = commandText;
    int start = -1;
    List<string> commandParts = new List<string>();

    //Running through the string looking for nested statemets starting with (
    for (int i = 0; i < processCommand.Length; i++)
    {
        //Any time we find a new open ( we want to start there
        if (processCommand[i] == '(')
            start = i;

        //If we find a close ) we will grab the nested statment and replace it
        if (processCommand[i] == ')')
        {
            //Grab the 3 parts of the string
            string preString = processCommand.Substring(0, start);
            string nestedCommand = processCommand.Substring(start, i - start + 1);
            string postString = processCommand.Substring(i + 1);

            //Add the nested command to the list
            commandParts.Add(nestedCommand);

            //Update the commandText replacing the nested command we removed with its index in the list
            processCommand = preString + "{" + (commandParts.Count - 1) + "}" + postString;

            //Go back the the beginning of the command and look for the next nested command
            i = 0;
            start = -1;
        }
    }
    //If start isnt -1 that means we found an open ( without a closing )
    if (start == -1)
    {
        //We want to add the final command the the list for processing too
        commandParts.Add(processCommand);

        //We're going to go through the command parts and replace the LIMIT
        for (int i = 0; i < commandParts.Count; i++)
        {
            string command = commandParts[i];
            Console.WriteLine(command);
            //We need to find the where the LIMIT is and extact the number
            int limitIndex = command.IndexOf("LIMIT");
            if (limitIndex != -1)
            {
                int startIndex = limitIndex + 6;
                //Assuming after the limit will be ), a space, or the end of the string
                int endIndex = command.IndexOf(')', startIndex);
                if (endIndex == -1)
                    endIndex = command.IndexOf(' ', startIndex);
                if (endIndex == -1)
                    endIndex = command.Length - 1;

                Console.WriteLine(startIndex);
                Console.WriteLine(endIndex);
                //Extract the number
                string limitNumber = command.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
                //Remove the LIMIT command. There should always be a space before so take that out too.
                command = command.Remove(limitIndex - 1, endIndex - limitIndex + 1);
                //Insert the top command with the number
                command = command.Replace("SELECT", "SELECT TOP " + limitNumber);
                //Update the list
                commandParts[i] = command;
            }
        }

        start = -1;
        //We need to go through the commands in reverse order and reassemble the complete command
        for (int i = 0; i < processCommand.Length; i++)
        {
            //If we find a { its a part of the command that needs to be replaced
            if (processCommand[i] == '{')
                start = i;
            if (processCommand[i] == '}')
            {
                string startString = processCommand.Substring(0, start);
                string midString = processCommand.Substring(start, i - start + 1);
                string endString = processCommand.Substring(i + 1);
                //Get the index of the command we need from the list
                int strIndex = Int32.Parse(midString.Substring(1, midString.Length - 2));

                processCommand = processCommand.Replace(midString, commandParts[strIndex]);

                //Go back to the start and look for the next
                i = 0;
                start = -1;
            }
        }

        commandText = processCommand;
    }
    else
    {
        LogManager.Write(LogLevel.Error, "Unmatched parentheses were found while processing a SQL command. Command: " + commandText);
    }

    return commandText;
}
```

Comment: Converting scripts from one db to another, might be very complicated and in some cases impossible, unless you know all the patterns of source db. your code is also too long to go though (at least for me)

Comment: If you're going to check for ```(``` and ```)```, you could always use a stack. Push each opening parenthesis onto the stack and as you come across the closing parenthesis you can pop one off. If you get to the end and you still have items on the stack, then the syntax is invalid. This would be useful if you needed to handle other characters, as well, since you could push and pop in order.